# How do I convert this mod_rewite rule to IIS7 UrlRewrite

Tags: iis, iis-7, rewrite, iis-6, iis-7.5

```
Options +Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Is what i would use in Apache mod rewite to make it so index.html is actually index.php

How can i do this in IIS ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="Default.aspx" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is what i have for my current config. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is this tagged with iis6?

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to IIS7's management console on the host or any machine that is running IIS7 and UrlRewrite then you can automate the conversions.

First of all, copy your `mod_rewrite` rules to a file and save as something like `mod_rw.htaccess`.

Launch IIS7's management console, navigate to your site. Launch the UrlRewrite feature:

[image]

On the right hand Actions Pane select *Import Rules*:

[image]

Click on the elipses button next to the Configuration File text box, locate and select `mod_rw.htaccess`:

[image]

Next click the *Import* button:

[image]

Upon clicking Import, your `mod_rewrite` rules will be imported and converted to IIS7's UrlRewrite 2.0 rule format.

Your can view the raw XML configuration by clicking on the XML View tab:

[image]

At this point, if you click on the *Back to Rules* link in the right hand action pane menu, the importer will ask if you want to save these rules. If this isn't the intended target machine then just copy what's in the Xml View tab and paste in the `web.config` belonging to the target site.

On a final note (and you may already know this), you can actually change the default document order so that `index.php` is preferred over `index.html`:

```
<defaultDocument>
    <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="index.php" /> <!-- <-- moved to top of list -->
        <add value="Default.htm" />
        <add value="Default.asp" />
        <add value="index.htm" />
        <add value="Default.aspx" />
        <add value="index.html" />
    </files>
</defaultDocument>
```